# GAE: Why does GAE perform worse than normalized return and advantages

Tags: python, numpy, reinforcement-learning

I'm implementing PPO with GAE as advantages. The following code is the way I compute GAE and returns according to OpenAI's baseline implementation.

```py
advantages = np.zeros_like(rewards)
last_adv = 0
for i in reversed(range(len(rewards))):
    delta = rewards[i] + nonterminals[i] * self._gamma * values[i+1] - values[i]
    advantages[i] = last_adv = delta + nonterminals[i] * gamma * lam * last_adv
returns = advantages + values[:-1]
advantages = normalize(advantages) # normalize advantages
```

One thing worth to be noted is that `values` has one more element than other arrays like `rewards` so that `values[-1]` can be used as the extra next state. However, this implementation performs way worse than simply normalized return and advantages given below

```py
returns = rewards
next_return = 0
for i in reversed(range(len(rewards))):
    returns[i] = rewards[i] + nonterminals[i] * gamma * next_return
    next_return = returns[i]

# normalize returns and advantages
values = normalize(values[:-1], np.mean(returns), np.std(returns))
advantages = normalize(returns - values)
returns = normalize(returns)
```

Without changing anything else, the above implementation constantly achieves the average score about `270+` in `gym` environment `LunarLanderContinuous-v2`. The GAE implementation, on the other hand, never achieve more than `100` score. See the following figure for an example, where the better one is run with the normalized implementation
[image]

What's wrong with my implementation?

In addition, here's the code for `normalize`

```py
def normalize(x, mean=0., std=1., epsilon=1e-8):
    x = (x - np.mean(x)) / (np.std(x) + epsilon)
    x = x * std + mean

    return x
```

Comment: definitely late, but GAE decays to return with lambda=1, so probably it's a matter of hyperparameters tuning

Answer (score 0):

Your code for computing the advantage seems correct. What does `normalize` do? Usually you *standardize* your data, meaning that you subtract its mean and divide by its standard deviation. I ask because in the second part of you code you pass the mean and the standard deviation of the return to the function `normalize`, while in the first portion you do not.

Also, why do you normalize `values` using `returns` in the second part of your code? It seems weird to me.

Finally, how do you train you V-function? (I assume that `values` contains the V-values). I found out that learning it as below

```
    for epoch in range(epochs_v):
        v_values = ... # compute your values using V
        a_values = ... # compute A as in your code
        target_values = v_values + a_values # generalized Bellman operator
        # optimize V on your dataset with minibatches and ADAM
```

works better than "one-shot fit"

```
    v_values = ... # compute your values using V
    a_values = ... # compute A as in your code
    target_values = v_values + a_values # generalized Bellman operator
    # fit V to target_values
```

Comment: Hi, @Simon. I've updated the code for `normalize`. I normalize `values` so that `values` would have the same mean and variance as `returns`. And I simply use `returns` as the target values, and use mean square error as the loss function for value function.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. What I would do is to normalize `returns` before and then to fit `values` to them. 
I have never heard of your way, I am going to try it.